# Forcing just one HTML page to open via SSL using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

I want to force all clients to use SSL to access an HTML file on my website. It is `snipprintslive.html` in my root folder: `www.stellamays.co.uk/sniprintslive.html`.

I’ve tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
#https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^sniprintslive https://stellamays.co.uk/sniprintslive [R=301,L]
```

This works for the rest of the site but access to `sniprintslive.html` gives “file not found” error.

I tried putting the page in a subfolder (nightmare for relative links but hey ho) and putting .htaccess file in the same folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} printsfolder/sniprintslive.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.stellamays.co.uk/printsfolder/sniprintslive.html$1 [R,L]
```

Again I received the same error.

I don't understand this programming language but wondered if it’s the `www` or `http:` stuff which is upsetting it.

Note that my server will work with .htaccess as I successfully forced the whole site to open with HTTPS using similar code.

Comment: Are you still interested in knowing why your original solution didn’t work?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with this...I was a bit scared of the code cos I didn't get to put my website in???!
but it worked perflectly

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /sniprintslive.html
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```